# Login Silverlight Website

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, authentication

Wich is the best (and safest) way to implement user login for a silverlight application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on where your authentication logic resides. If you store your data on a server and you communicate with it via RIA services, then you have access to a built in authentication framework. [Here](http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2010/07/02/silverlight-and-wcf-ria-services-5-authentication.aspx) is an example.

If you do communication via plain WCF, then you can still do authentication over WCF in many ways.

Example of using Windows Authentication over WCF: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744835(v=VS.95).aspx

For your question: best and safest....Both are good for either server-communication method you use. If these don't seem `best` to you, you can always write your own security.